# WPF UI Scenario - Best way to add a functionality in 50 views?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, binding, wpftoolkit, wpfdatagrid

I want some suggestions to implement this functionality with a neat design and without any code replication. I have an application with many views and grid control in most of the views. I need to add an export functionality (export records to excel).The grid control supports this OOB, just need to call 'Grid.Export()'. I am planning a UI button on the side of every grid and call this method.

So, obviously I need to write the code in code-behind only since I need the control's instance to invoke the method. But, I like to keep the code in one place and somehow invoke the code from all Xamls. (all WPF views).

One technique is to write a BaseView class and derive all Views from this.

But would like to know if WPF suppots any techniques by which I can achieve this. (behaviours etc..?)

Thanks,
Mani

Comment: This is where MVVM comes about...a single ViewModel for your varying Views performing the logic via a DelegateCommand defined on the ViewModel and consumed by the View.

Comment: NO. This logic cannot be in the View Model. The whole point of MVVM is for separating the UI and logic. In here, the UI control instance is needed and shouldnt be passed on to the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of solutions is to use WPF routed command.

*Note: I wrote this answer with the assumption that your "View" is a subclass of Window class.*

First, add a custom routed command to your project.

```
public static class MyCommands
{
    private static readonly RoutedUICommand exportCommand = new RoutedUICommand("description", "Export", typeof(MyCommands));

    public static RoutedUICommand ExportCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return exportCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

In each View, set your custom command to Button.Command and bind a target object to Button.CommandTarget.

```
<Button Command="local:MyCommands.ExportCommand" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1}">Export</Button>
```

Firnally, in your Application class (named App by default), register a command binding between your custom command and Window.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        var binding = new CommandBinding(MyCommands.ExportCommand, Export, CanExport);
        CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(typeof(Window), binding);
    }

    private void Export(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.Source refers to the object is bound to Button.CommandTarget.
        var dataGrid = (DataGrid)e.Source;

        // Export data.
    }

    private void CanExport(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Assign true to e.CanExecute if your application can export data.
        e.CanExecute = true;
    }
}
```

Now, App.Export is invoked when user click a button.

Sample is available [here](https://cid-d4a8c5a0a96835be.office.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/stackoverflow/RegisteringCommandHandlerForAllWindows.zip).

Answer (score 3):

Create a `UserControl` that includes both the datagrid and the export button. In effect, make it part of the grid itself.

Use this `UserControl` instead of the default datagrid in all of your views, and you're done.

Furthermore, if you ever have to modify the look and feel of your button or its behaviour, you have only one place in which to change it, and it will be updated in all of your views.

Comment: Well thats a lot of rework to change the whole view for all the 50+ views. Hence thinking if there is anything we could do like the Behaviours...

Comment: @Mani What rework does it require? You just create one control and then find-and-replace all instances of the datagrid with that control, which Visual Studio can do for you. The whole thing can be done in 20 minutes, and 15 of those are for creating and wiring up the button. Add 5 minutes if you also need to add a namespace declaration to the xaml files.